Issues setting up NGINX, getting invalid variable name in nginx.conf file when I didn't make changes to it
I'm trying to set up nginx and after a create a symbolic link between sites-available and sites-enabled, I get this error when I use sudo nginx -t:
nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:61;

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I did not edit this nginx.conf file.
Tried back tracking the whole process and this error only occurs after creating the symbolic link.
This is the nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
                # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml applicatio>

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}


Hey welcome to the site, I don't think anyone can help you if you don't show the applicable information.  For starters, please share /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.  Also symbolic links ln -s ./source-file ./destination-file usually in Linux.  Remove any sensitive keys from your config; give it placeholder values.  I know you said you didn't edit it, but I don't think many people remember how default nginx configuration looks like.  Finally, please learn about formatting, and how to properly, this article discusses both:  structure your questions better.

You have a syntax error in the file you linked probably.

@mikey Did you get this resolved?

This ended up too long for the comments section, maybe something here helps you:
Cut-off configuration

I assume that # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml applicatio> was copied from the console and is not cut-off or syntax problem correct?

Otherwise you have some truncated configuration that can't be understood.
Finally two other things:

include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

If you have some weird configurations here (that is in your sites-enabled folder as 'batch files/other configs that does not really mean it's nginx related', I think this will also be parsed by the nginx 'include parser').   If one of your files (or your website has syntax errors this will be included and then fails
Solution: Try making sure you only include  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf and verify your websites;

Your symbolic links as you suspect the whole time, you can straight up just add your website config .conf INTO ./sites-enabled; it does not have to be a symbolic link from ./sites-available.

Solution: Add the .conf website into ./sites-enabled, bypassing it as a symbolic link.
